# Simple Java animation with Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am learning to use Java Swing and have made a simple animation that makes a small shape bounce around the predetermined borders of a panel. The program works well, but I am looking for feedback in terms of quality and any improvements or alternative methods that could be used in such an application.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

final public class Tester {

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private int oneX = 7;
    private int oneY = 7;

    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = true;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean right = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tester().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocation(375, 55);
        moveIt();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(3, 3, this.getWidth()-6, this.getHeight()-6);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(6, 6, this.getWidth()-12, this.getHeight()-12);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(oneX, oneY, 6, 6);
        }
    }

    private void moveIt() {
        while(true){
            if(oneX >= 283){
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            if(oneX <= 7){
                right = true;
                left = false;
            }
            if(oneY >= 259){
                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            if(oneY <= 7){
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            if(up){
                oneY--;
            }
            if(down){
                oneY++;
            }
            if(left){
                oneX--;
            }
            if(right){
                oneX++;
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception exc){}
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: import.java.awt.BorderLayout should be more efficient

Comment: try using a switch instead of if/else sta

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Things I would fix:

Don't do this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
```

It could be problematic for the compiler to import a bunch of packages at once. If two packages provide the same type, both are imported, and the type is used in the class, a compile-time error occurs. This is described in [JLS 6.5.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#32799):

> Otherwise, if a type of that name is declared by more than one type-import-on-demand declaration of the compilation unit, then the name is ambiguous as a type name; a compile-time error occurs.

In addition, it also saves a bit of memory.  And your IDE (if you use one), should have the ability to do this automatically.

---

[The serializable class `DrawPanel` does not declare a `static final serialVersionUID` field of type `long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it) (thanks to @GilbertLeBlanc for the link):

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

---

Don't **ever** do this:

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
}
```

Say that you do get an [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) thrown at you. You aren't handling it right now in any way.  At least print a stack trace to help you solve problems you may encounter in the future:

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

It was also mentioned in the comments to catch specific `Exceptions`.  Here there is no real need to do that since only an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) is being thrown.  When you do need to catch multiple `Exceptions`, [some people might tell you to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception):

```
catch (IOException io)
{
    io.printStackTrace()
}
catch (InterruptedException ie)
{
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

But you could also do this:

```
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Right now there are some hard-coded values:

```
if(oneX >= 283)
if(oneX <= 7)
...
```

I would store those values in variables, and then I would make it so that it is more scalable.  For example:

```
int xScale = 280;
int yScale = xScale / 40;
```

That way, you only have to change one value in order to scale your different values.  This is just an example, *and has not been implemented in my code*.  I left this for you to do on your own.

### Recommendations that are optional:

You have a lot of `if` statements with braces:

```
if(down)
{
    oneY++;
}
```

If you don't expand on them (which I don't see a need to), you can save some LOC:

```
if (down) oneY++;
```

---

Right now you are setting the location:

```
frame.setLocation(375, 55);
```

You don't have to do this, but I prefer the [OS to set the location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform%28boolean%29):

```
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

You could also set the [frame to the center of the window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29):

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

But I never liked that too much.  It makes your program seem like a pop-up, which I despise.

---

I always do `frame.setVisible(true)` after I am completely finished setting up the frame.

---

Right now your are doing this with your braces:

```
void someMethod(int someInt){
    // ...
}
```

Since you are a beginner, I would recommend lining up your braces (I still do this, and I've been programming for a while):

```
void someMethod(int someInt)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is a matter of taste, and it is perfectly fine to stay with what you are doing right now.

---

You might note that this:

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Is a bit different than your usual:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

They both do the same thing, but one uses [variable arity parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java/2926653#2926653).

### Final code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

final public class Test
{

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private int oneX = 7;
    private int oneY = 7;

    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = true;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean right = true;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new Test().go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        moveIt();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(3, 3, this.getWidth() - 6, this.getHeight() - 6);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(6, 6, this.getWidth() - 12, this.getHeight() - 12);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(oneX, oneY, 6, 6);
        }
    }

    private void moveIt()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (oneX >= 283)
            {
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            if (oneX <= 7)
            {
                right = true;
                left = false;
            }
            if (oneY >= 259)
            {
                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            if (oneY <= 7)
            {
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            if (up) oneY--;
            if (down) oneY++;
            if (left) oneX--;
            if (right) oneX++;
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful insights! Thank you for putting that much into the answer. I didn't even know about setting location based on OS and I'm going to try that to see how I like it. It seems more reasonable in a lot of ways what with people having different screen resolutions. My only question is what does: private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; really do?

Comment: I just tried setting the location based on OS and I like that a LOT better! Thank you so much for showing me that!

Comment: @Jeremy Johnson: serialVersionUID; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc appologies if I'm missing the point here, but doesn't that mean that the serialVersionUID is not indicated in a class that doesn't implement Serializable?

Comment: @Jeremy Johnson: A serialVersionID is not necessary unless the class, or a class you're extending, implements Serializable.

Comment: That's good info to keep in the hip pocket. Thanks for clarification with this. I really appreciate all the help that I can get.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson I've updated my answer a bit further since you are a beginner.  I've now split my answer into two sections, one of things I would definitely fix, one into recommendations that are optional.  I've also added some additional notes.  All the notes have been implemented into my code.

Comment: @syb0rg He's placing the braces according to "Java" (Oracle) standard, nothing wrong with that. This is a matter of taste and IMHO has nothing to do with being a beginner. You should mention that, again IMHO. It's no big deal, but would be good to mention.

Comment: @Marc-Andre That's why it is in the section "Recommendations that are optional".  It is up for him to decide, but in my mind, it makes coding easier.  You are right that there is nothing wrong with it.  I did make an edit to the question to state that it is a matter of taste.

Comment: I appreciate any and all insights. I don't believe there is a such thing as useless information. Some might be more useful or more correct than others or may suit needs better in different circumstances, but it's always good to keep an extra way in the back of your mind just in case. Who knows, one of my professors this year might say that it HAS to be done this way or that. It's good to be flexible.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but after reading through some more Java docs, I'm about 101% certain that there is no need to include a serialVersionUID in this answer (unless the class were to change to one that implements Serializable) since the number is just a reference for deserialization.

Comment: It only matters if you plan on storing and retrieving objects using serialization directly.  It's always a good idea to include it.

Comment: Usually `InterruptedException` requires special handling, you should not place it in a multi-catch. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Answer (score 6):

Your code has a lot of magic numbers in it.

```
if(oneX >= 283){
   right = false;
   left = true;
}
```

What is special about 283? What does it actually mean? If you define a constant that happens to have the value of 283, it will be much easier to update your code if the value needs to change.

---

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(10);
} catch (Exception exc){}
```

Catching `Exception` is bad. You always want to catch the most specific exception you can to do what you need. In this case, `InterruptedException` would be the correct exception to catch. This is not a great example because there is only one exception that can be thrown. However, in the future, it will prevent you for accidentally handling and unexpected exception the wrong way.

Additionally, you are not doing anything with the exception. In general, this is a bad practice. Exceptions are thrown for a reason and should not be ignored without some thought. If you know you don't care what the exception is cause by, add a comment to explain your reasoning to anyone who might see the code later.

Comment: I used 283 because the window is not resizable and the borders seem to make the shape meet the edge best with that number, I started with different numbers and kept changing them until it seemed to line up more accurately. I like the idea of defining something like: private int rightBorder = 283, though. Did not know that about exceptions, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You get a good review from @syb0rg. I'm going to tell you something that will help you in the long run. If you create any application in Swing in future try to use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to prevent any *unnatural behavior*. So the code will be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            new Tester().go();
        }
    });
}
```

Now you will ask "Why should I use this?". Here is a good answer from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-neded).

Comment: I learn something new today, +1.

Comment: I imagine this is particularly useful in larger GUIs, yes?

Comment: @JeremyJohnson larger as well as for smaller cause you can't rely on your Swing app as all components are not thread safe. So why *take chance*? Take advantage of the API or you can implement you own thread safety from scratch, but I wouldn't go there.

Comment: @tintinmj I do usually use these animation GUIs in their own separate thread now when I'm working on a test that involves other operations, too. Especially if one of the other operations is sound.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having all the direction `boolean`s, `up`, `left`, `right` and `down`, you can use `velocityX` and `velocityY` (which I will call `xV` and `yV` from now on). This will reduce the number of lines by quite a bit, because other than requiring only 2 variables rather than 4, you only have to check vertical and horizontal collision, and invert the velocity on impact.

In the beginning, set `xV` and `yV` to 1 and place the ball somewhere on the field:

```
if (x < 0 || x >= width) xV *= -1;
```

Same goes for the y values of course. Then, in the update method:

```
x += xV; y += yV;
```

When the ball hits the right wall, the horizontal speed will change to -1, which means x will decrease each time.

You can also change the starting values to 2 or 3 to make the ball go faster.

Comment: Also, Java's window's width is 6px smaller than its screen and the height 29px, so you were right about the 283 (if the height is indeed 256px).

Answer (score 3):

You should not sleep on the event dispatch thread (EDT) as this blocks Swing from processing events, including painting events.

You should use a javax.swing.Timer instead of a while loop:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // update variables
           // do not sleep
           // only need to repaint the panel, not entire frame
           drawPanel.repaint();
        }
      });
timer.start();
```

Other notes:

- if do not use EXIT_ON_CLOSE, you should add a WindowListener to stop the timer when window closes
- you could only repaint the bounding box of the old and new location with repaint(x, y, width, height) for performance
- See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html